# How to pass multiple labels into Huggingface transformers Trainer

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Huggingface transformer [Trainer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html) says "your model can accept multiple label arguments (use the label_names in your TrainingArguments to indicate their name to the Trainer)". Anyone know the correct format to pass multiple labels into the trainer? It doesn't seem clear from the documentation. I would like to avoid putting all of the labels into one label column, since some have multiple labels at the same time, so there would be all the combinations of column names (there is a 1 in the row for each label that a comment applies to, so like one-hot encoding with possibly multiple 1's in a row).

Comment: Please post us a minimal reproducible example and add the version of transformers you are using. It is always time-consuming and sometimes impossible to reproduce an error.

Comment: @cronoik I removed the mention of the error. I'm really just asking what is the proper format.

Comment: `label_names` is a list of strings.

Comment: @cronoik yes but does that pertain to labels in one column or multiple columns?